# IIS - Acess denied when browsing a file

Tags: css, iis, permission-denied

I have 2 folders under my application in IIS.  When I right click on a file in folder 1 and click browse, I can see the file just fine (its a css file).  When I do the same thing on a fie under folder 2 (also a css file). I get a

"ACCESS DENIED.  It seems that you have tried to perform an operation which you are not permitted to perform.You cannot view this URL as a guest. You must login."

network traffic in IE and Chrome say 200.

Any help? I have no clue whats going on

**SOLUTION**

This is more of a I was dumb scenario as opposed to a solution.  When the file was downloaded from a location to be moved into the folder, the file itself had the text "Access Denied....." in it.  It had nothing to do with IIS.  Once I fixed the download problem I got the correct file and moved it to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that one of those folders is a virtual folder? If so then you need to set NT permissions for user running the application pool.

For example if your website and folder that works is under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\website1 but folder that doesn't work is a virtual folder under d:\some_other_folder\ then you need to open security settings for this folder and give permissions to system user running the application pool.